# any nice CSS design for non-artistic web developer?

Tags: css

Honestly I'm very bad at CSS and not good at dealing with color / design.

Are there any helpful sites for things like pre-made, nicely skinned component, or layout of the whole site?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is awfully vague.. and doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few:

http://www.oswd.org/

http://openwebdesign.org/

http://www.solucija.com/free-templates

http://www.opensourcetemplates.org/

for skeletal layouts: http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/

and few a few css tutorials http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/index.html

Comment: There ya go Joe, I upvoted yours to compensate. :)

Comment: To be fair, I was going to anyway and forgot.

Answer (score 1):

I used the "[Free CSS Template](http://www.freecsstemplate.net/)" website.  When I created my web site they didn't have a lot of designs, but the ones they did have were clean, complete, and elegant.  Pure XHTML and CSS.  I had no trouble tweaking to fit my needs.

Comment: One day I will work out why somebody downvoted this... the referenced website is perfectly valid as an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: same thing for my accepted answer...why the sudden down vote on an answer that was accepted over a week ago?

Answer (score 1):

A slight tangent, but you may find the book [The Principles of Beautiful Web Design](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/design1/) an interesting read. It is aimed more toward non-designers looking to expand their design awareness.

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/